# exclude tasks from the task that my task depends on

Tags: gradle

I created task which depends on `build`.

```
task packageJar(dependsOn: build, type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.xxxx.util.KiePackageCreator'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

But `build` task invokes other tasks like `checkstyle`, `test` and etc.
How to exclude them?

I can do it through console `-x` but how to do it inside task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply disable the tasks, by setting it's `enabled` property to false in the root of the script:

```
test.enabled = false
```

But in that case, those tasks won't ever run. If you just need them to not running if some other task is called, then you have to use execution graph:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    taskGraph ->
        if (taskGraph.hasTask(packageJar)) {
            test.enabled = false
        }
}
```

But not sure at the moment, whether it is possible to change this property when the graph is ready. If not, then you can make a variable and in the tasks, you want to exclude, add the `doFirst` block, which will throw the `StopExecutionException` according to this variable value.

Comment: I see. So there is no inbox simple solution like `exlude: test, checkstyle` and etc.?

Comment: @user1432980 the simpliest is to use `-x` falg, but if you can't and don't want to exclude some task permanently with `task.enabled = false`, you have to do such a complex solution. Read about it here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10E33

Comment: Oh! see. I'll look into it.

Comment: @user1432980 sure, if those task are executed after the `packageJar` you could simply skip them according to the `packageJar` task status, but they are executed before and this is the reason, why it's not as easy